# php preg_replace

Tags: php

I need to allow only letter, numbers, and underscores(_).

Anything else replace to space symbol ( _ ).

What's wrong with my regex pattern?

```
<?php
$val = 'dasd Wsd 23 /*~`';
$k = preg_replace('/[a-Z0-9_]+$/', '_', $val);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to add the `^` which inverts the characters that are matched inside the character class.

```
$val = 'dasd Wsd 23 /*~`';
$k = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '_', $val);
```

Another way to do it is to have it match non "word" characters, which is anything that isn't a letter, number, or underscore.

```
$val = 'dasd Wsd 23 /*~`';
$k = preg_replace('/\W/', '_', $val);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[a-Z]` matches nothing.. You can use `\W` to match non-word chars:

`preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', $val)`

Additionally the `$` sign only matches at the end of a string.