# php preg_replace with Unicode chars

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've a question similar this question: [php preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058405/php-preg-replace)

In that question, He/She want to allow only letters and numbers and _, but I want to allow only numbers, letters and **Unicode (non-latin)** letters and numbers (I think, I should use the Unicode values of this (for example `U+1F70`)).

What can I do? Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of listing the unicode ranges yourself, you should use an Unicode character class as explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\d\p{L}]/u', "", $str);
```

If you repeatedly try to construct or decipher regexps, don't forget to check out [Is there anything like RegexBuddy in the open source world?](http://web.archive.org/web/20131229163953/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) for utilities that help with that.